# Duplicating an element and restyle it

Tags: css, tumblr

I am making a tumblr theme based off perfect symmetry. So where in the page I have a the original post, I want it reflected to the right.
Basically for every post, there will be a second post, equal in every way, except it will be on the right side, also applying the originals left margin to its right; and styled using `transform: scaleX(-1);`

Comment: So.. What is your question?

Comment: How do I duplicate these posts, and apply said stylings?

Comment: Do it in your template. Copy and paste the posts loop to duplicate it. It's a mess but it's faster (to write and to load) than doing it in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You can't truly duplicate content with only CSS. You could use CSS3 properties such as

```
box-reflect
```

but [check out browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-reflect) first

To duplicate content in a *safer* way, you should considerate using Javascript or Php if you can.

Comment: What would be the Javascript/JQuery method, like I said, this is for tumblr